# How to see a list of posts upvoted by myself

Tags: support, user-interface, up-votes

Over the years that I've been on MSE, I've encountered many many good questions and answers. Recently, I've been trying to collect some beautiful math problems for others to play with, and I wanted to use those that I've seen here, too. Usually, I upvote the posts that I like, but rarely I bookmark them, so I can see almost non of the posts I liked in my "bookmarks" list. Is there a way that I can see a list of those post that I've upvoted during my years on the site?

Comment: Since it already exists, it's not a good feature request... :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right. Shouldn't we have a tag for those like me that when asking the question don't know whether the feature exists or not? :-)

Comment: [meta-tag:support].

Comment: @AsafKaragila Never had thought of "support" like that. :-) Thanks for your immediate responses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/229831/?tab=votes&sort=upvote

Only you have access to this page, though, not even the moderators can see into its content. Anyone else can swap the number for their user number.

Comment: I will add that this link should work for everybodu: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote (The old `users/current` trick.)